# SQLTransaction does not work in c#

Tags: c#, sqltransaction

I have opened transaction inside one function ,this function calls stored procedure,which updates data in SqlDataTable.After i return from this function without rollback or commit and call other function, which must return data from same DataTable.After i must call first function to commit or rollback transaction.But my second function does not work.Can you help me?

Comment: Please share the code..

Comment: Do you use the same connection for all commands that you use on your DB?

Comment: Thank You @AravinthKannan ,@mslliviu. I used other connections..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your SqlTransaction object is defined in the first function, and when it goes out of scope (is destroyed or disposed) it carries out an auto-rollback. Its difficult to be sure without any code example, but this is a scenairo which would give you the observed behavioiur.

Comment: Thank You.Now i use same connection,but i have this in my first function - trans = conn.BeginTransaction();

Comment: how and where  can i define it?

Comment: Open the connection outside both the functions.
Create the Transaction outside both the functions and attach to the connection.
Call your functions
Commit the transaction.
Close the connection.